# Using jQuery-Smooth-Scroll from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, smooth-scrolling

I am currently using jQuery-Smooth-Scroll to smoothly scroll up and down to various anchor positions on one of my pages (Page 1). However, what I would also like to be able to do is, from another page (Page 2), link to Page1 (appending #bookmark to the url) and have jQuery-Smooth-Scroll pick up on the fact I am calling the page with a #bookmark and have it smoothly scroll down to the relevant position once the page has completed loading. I don't know if this is a possibility or not?

This is the version of Smooth-Scroll that I'm using:

https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

I'm still relatively new to jQuery so I may be overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, you want to put a call into the smooth scroll function when the page is finished loading. in jQuery, it's using $(document).ready(function () { your code } );

You'll need to put something in to parse your url to extract the #bookmark and then call the smooth scroll.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I don't suppose you'd know how to do that using javascript would you (I mean, extracting the #bookmark from the url)?

Answer (score 7):

Ajma's answer should be sufficient, but for completeness:

```
alert(location.hash)
```

Edit: a more complete example:

```
// on document.ready {
if (location.hash != '') {
    var a = $("a[name=" + location.hash.substring(1) + "]");
    // note that according to w3c specs, the url hash can also refer to the id
    // of an element. if so, the above statement becomes
    // var a = $(location.hash);
    if (a.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(a).offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    }
}
// }
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information on this. I am seeing a problem though where it seems the simple presence of having a hash within the URL seems to be making it jump straight down to that bookmark on the page, rather than leaving it for the jquery to handle using smooth scroll. I'm wondering if instead of linking to Page1 from Page2 with #bookmark in the url, whether I will need to use something like ?bookmark, then look for a ? instead of hash, then smooth scroll to that bookmark that it found after the ?

Comment: it's location.search for the stuff after ?

Comment: I see the problem. You can use a fake hash that does not actually exist in the document (#detail-foo) and then let jQuery scroll to the `div[id=detail]` or `a[name=detail]`, but this is not elegant. Its actually worth posting as a separate question.

Comment: Excellent suggestion Salman, thanks, and yes I think I'll post this as a new question just in case there is a more elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: One should also note that the usage of "html, body" as selector is because some browsers require the html tag to animate the scroll, other browsers require the body tag to scroll. jQuery will select both and try to animate the scroll **on both**. That is not a problem, the intended effect is still the same. However, if you add a complete function to execute after the animation has finished, that logic will be **executed twice** (!). Counter this by setting a local boolean variable check for an early exit at the beginning of the complete function logic.